# Android SAX Parser not reading net work loaded document (Character de/encoding issue)?

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

I'm using Android to read a document off the net, surprise I'm writing here because I have an issue.   For lots of sites I have no issues, but for some sites the xml parser in android is "grumpy".   I suspect it's something to do with the Character encoding, but I'm not sure exactly what.   In particular if I download the file with "wget" and feed it to android, it works fine....

Android's error message,
   03-23 21:54:47.383: ERROR/xml(9062): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 62: syntax error

The xml when I download it seems fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
    ...
```

My sample android application....

```
package com.example.android.helloactivity;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {

    class EnclosureHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                throws SAXException {
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            Log.i("xml", "lname is : " + qName);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello_activity);

        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new URL(
                    "http://www.hbo.com/podcasts/billmaher/podcast.xml")
                    .openStream());
            sp.parse(is, new EnclosureHandler());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("xml", t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would just note that, assuming the xml declaration is line 0 and columns are numbered from 1 (anybody know?), then line 1 column 62 is immediately after the first xmlns declaration. I don't know how the namespace could be throwing it off, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that character encoding is not the issue.   The HBO.com web site returns different content based on the USER-AGENT: header.  So if you use Android to talk with the hbo.com site, they return a message about how you could use there own android client to access the site.   They probably are trying to help people using web browsers.   Changing the USER-AGENT then caused the above program to get the correct (and parse-able) xml document.